# while($stmt->fetch()) only looping once

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using `while($stmt->fetch())` to loop though the results I get from a MySQL Query, and under certain conditions, I'm only getting one result.
I'm guessing this is becuase I've got 2 `$stmt`'s. but I thought this sort of thing was supported. I guess I'm making a rookie mistake, I've been used to non-prepared statements for too long!

```
    $db = mysqlConnect();
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare("SELECT id, uploadtype FROM uploads ORDER BY displayorder DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $uploadtype);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo 'ID = ' . $id . '<br />';
        if ($uploadtype == 'single') {
            $stmt->prepare("SELECT title, description FROM singles WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($title, $description);
            $stmt->fetch();
            ?>
            Title: <? echo $title; ?><br />
            Description: <? echo $description; ?><br />
            <a href="edit.php?id=<? echo $id; ?>">Edit</a><br />
            <?
        }
    }
```

This only echo's one ID. I'm guessing this is the problem because when I use the following, I get all IDs echoed.

```
$db = mysqlConnect();
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("SELECT id, uploadtype FROM uploads ORDER BY displayorder DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $uploadtype);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'ID = ' . $id . '<br />';
}
```

How can I get around this problem? I'm thinking I don't understand prepared statements quite right.
EDIT:
Now changed to this, but getting `invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt` on line starting `<error>`.

```
$db = mysqlConnect();
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    if (!$limit) {
        $stmt->prepare("SELECT id FROM uploads WHERE uploadtype = 'youtube' ORDER BY displayorder DESC");
    } else {
        $stmt->prepare("SELECT id FROM uploads WHERE uploadtype = 'youtube' ORDER BY displayorder DESC LIMIT 0, ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $limit);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $stmt2 = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt2->prepare("SELECT title, description, url FROM youtube WHERE id = ?");
        <error>$stmt2->bind_param('i', $id);
        <error>$stmt2->execute();
        <error>$stmt2->bind_result($title, $description, $url);
        <error>while ($stmt2->fetch()) {
            $title = stripslashes($title);
            $description = stripslashes($description);
            $url = stripslashes($url);
            ?>
            <class id="item">
                <?
                if ($gettitle) echo 'Title: ' . $title . '<br/>';
                if ($getdescription) echo 'Description: ' . $description . '<br />';
                ?>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<? echo $url; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </class><br />
            <?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another statement variable.  Replace the second usage (`SELECT title...`) with a separate variable (e.g., `$stmt2` for lack of a better name).

```
    if ($uploadtype == 'single') {
        $stmt2 = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt2->prepare("SELECT title, description FROM singles WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt2->bind_param('i', $id);
        ...
```

Otherwise the next `fetch` in the outer loop is run against the second statement.

Comment: Agreed. Your only executing the loop once before rewriting the contents of $stmt.

Comment: Thought it could be something like that. It works on one page, but I keep getting `invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt` on certain pages. I'll edit it will some more code, and the error lines.

Comment: Also needed new `$db` (called it `$db2`). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same variable name (`$stmt`) if  you're doing nested queries like this.  Name the inner statement something different.